# Submit form thru javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i submit a form when picking a date? im trying to call it on field change but its not working, maybe i have to do this in the javascript part.

I have this

```js
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   Calendar.setup({
   inputField  : "element_4_3",
   baseField    : "element_4",
   displayArea  : "calendar_4",
   button   : "cal_img_4",
   ifFormat  : "%e %B, %Y",
   onSelect  : selectDate
   });
  </script>
```

```html
<span id="calendar_4">Data Especifica:
  <img id="cal_img_4" class="datepicker" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="Pick a date." onChange="this.form.submit();"> 
  </span>
```

how can i do this?
thanks

Comment: You've left out `selectDate`

Comment: iv left out? what do you mean?

Comment: What is Calendar class/function? Where has it defined?

Comment: datepicker is a js script, i was thinking i could put a submit.form() after the onSelect to activate form. any sugestions?

Comment: The script you're showing us uses `onSelect: selectDate`. There is no indication of what that method does, but based on your question is almost certain that the modifications would have to be made inside that function. We need to see it if we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: I got this script from here: http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/ @meagar